# Difference between Google "OpenID Connect" and "sign-in with Google"?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, google-oauth, google-openid

I want users to my website to use Google Accounts to authenticate / sign in to my website.  The primary **use case** being users will edit and generate content and we want to log ownership in a secure way.  We are not interested in obtaining users Google data, we just want a means to authenticate users.

After googling, I came across some documentation, which seems to explain how to do this [OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0 for Login)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#authenticatingtheuser).  But the documentation immediately says "Note: If you want to provide a “sign-in with Google” button for your website or app, we recommend using Google+ Sign-In, ...", which if you follow the link ultimately takes you to [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/).

What's the difference between these two pages of documentation? Why does the first tell you to go to the second while *not saying the first is deprecated*? Are both/either suitable for my use case? All it says is "we recommend" **I want to know WHY, WHY do they recommend it**?

UPDATE: I also found yet another link which seems to be documenting another approach https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer I think this is just for "Authorization" i.e. authorizing your app to make google api calls to get user data, so cannot be used for authenticating/sign-in.

BTW I'm building my website with a Scala Spray BE REST API & NG JS FE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A comparison of the two is available [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/openidconnect/index).

Google+ Sign-In with profile scope

- Has Google client libraries for authenticating with OAuth 2.0, which includes support for Google+ and other Google services (like getting social information on a user). Also this can make implementing easier and requires less boiler plate code
- Has the Google+ Sign-In button to simplify sign-in   Has no pre-built widgets
- Supports over-the-air Android installs

OAuth login is primarily just for authentication *at a lower level*, that is by making raw HTTP requests, no API.

OpenID Connect protocols (OAuth 2.0 login)
[Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in) supports OIDC interoperability if you configure with the openid scope and get the user profile using getOpenIdConnect.

[OAuth 2.0 login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) supports OIDC directly. Use it for signing in users to apps that do not need social features and run on platforms not supported by Google+ Sign-In.

Comment: I don't agree with your initial summary, but your link does indeed contain a useful table that compares them.  I'm editing your answer to include the table, then I'm accepting this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Doh! Useful table is now a 404.