# Authenticate with "Sign in with Google" with Spray

Tags: scala, authentication, openid, google-oauth, spray

I managed to find an example of some kind of Google authentication in a [unmerged fork of spray](https://github.com/thenewmotion/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-routing/openid-connect-routing-app/src/main/scala/spray/examples/GoogleAuthentication.scala).  According to the documentation on [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) and this [Java example](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java) it's not quite what I expect.  It doesn't use the google API packages e.g. `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2`, it has some manual paths, e.g. `private val authServer = Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")`, it mentions some things not mentioned at all in the java example, e.g. `redirect_uri` and `grant_type`, etc, etc.  I think the example is just for "Authorization" i.e. authorizing your app to make google api calls to get user data, so cannot be used for authenticating/sign-in.

What's the difference here? Are there any examples on how to do this with Google+ Sign-In? BONUS: Why is the fork unmerged?

Related question [Difference between Google "OpenID Connect" and "sign-in with Google"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471639/difference-between-google-openid-connect-and-sign-in-with-google)